# Nas4free (freeBSD) wont make it past bootloader without keyboard?

Tags: freebsd

I've got an old Compaq machine re-purposed as a Home NAS using [Nas4free](http://www.nas4free.org/). I've had it connected up to a monitor and keyboard (PS/2) for a while, (which boots fine, no issues) but I would like to have it boot and run with no peripherals.

However when I remove the keyboard, it never gets past the bootloader screen. Specifically, this is what it says:

```
-
FreeBSD/x86 boot
Default: 0:ad(0,a)/boot/loader
boot: 7
```

Now I've been through the BIOS settings, there isn't an option to not check for a keyboard, nor is there an option to not halt on error.

I should mention that I was originally running *FreeNAS 8*, however due to issues with plugins and the like I've moved to nas4Free (the old *FreeNAS 7*). This issue was *not* present using FreeNAS 8.

**Further Info**:

- *Nas4free* version 9.1.01 (based on *FreeBSD* 9.1 RELEASE) [See here](http://wiki.nas4free.org/doku.php#current_release)
- x86 Pentium III, 800mhz
- 512 MB RAM

Am I on the right track, is this a "your keyboard must be connected" issue, or is it something else? Is there a possible workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's causing your issue, but BIOS is a good guess. I would also say, I would consider different hardware. ZFS is not going to perform well with 512MB of RAM.

Comment: But if it was strictly a BIOS issue, wouldn't FreeNAS 8 have the same issue? Also I'm using software RAID 5, not ZFS. I know ZFS is resource hungry :).